# Help me understand this notation: Remainder of the power = $a = q_1d+r_1 \Rightarrow a^n = (q_1d+r_1)^n = q_*d+r^{n}_{1}, \;r^n_{1}\le d^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I'm not sure if I wrote the Tex code right so here is a screenshot:
[image]

(the text says: "Remainder of the power:(...) with (...). If (...), the remainder is (...), otherwise we divide (...) by d and that way we get the remainder.")

I understand most of the notation except that asterisk in $q_*d$  and the $r\binom{n}{1}$. I understand what a combination is and I can see that they are here because Newton's binom is applied somehow, I just don't see how. I am not even sure if that is a combination because the notation isn't even quite the same.

I also don't understand why the remainder is divided by the divisor (I get it it's for the sake of simplification but why the divisor specifically?)

Comment: I've corrected your code, so it's consistent with the screenshot. What do you not understand?

Comment: @Bernard I don't understand what that asterisk means and what that n over 1 means, if it's not about combinations

Comment: $q_*$ doesn't mean anything in particular, it just says it is not  $q_1$  (it is *another* quotient). For the rest, binomial coefficients have nothing to do in this notation: it denotes $r_1$ raised to the power $n$, that's all.

Comment: @Bernard I see, I still don't understand how do you get from one formula to the other.

Comment: It comes from expanding $q_1d+r_1$ by the binomial formula. All terms will be multiples of $q_1d$, hence of $d$, except the last, which is $r_1^n$

Comment: @Bernard I tried to expand it for the cube and the square and while I get the r^n bit I don't get the $q_* d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $q_1$, $q_*$ and $r_1$ are just some numbers, and $r_1^n$ is $r_1$ to the power $n$.
The subscripts $1$ and $*$ don't have any particular meaning except to show that these are different numbers that play similar roles in the text.

We begin from a number $a$, which has a remainder of $r_1$ when divided by $d$; then $a = q_1 d + r_1$ for some $q_1$ and $r_1 < d$.
We want to compute the remainder of $a^n$ when it's divided by $d$.
Of course, $a^n = (q_1 d + r_1)^n$.
Now we use the binomial formula on the second expression:
$$
  (q_1 d + r_1)^n = (q_1 d)^n + n (q_1 d)^{n-1} r_1 + \cdots + \binom{n}{k} (q_1 d)^{n-k} (r_1)^k + \cdots + (r_1)^n.
$$
Notice that every term except the rightmost one is divisible by $d$, which means that their sum is also divisible by $d$, and hence it has the form $q_* d$ for some number $q_*$.
So we have $a^n = (q_1 d + r_1)^n = q_* d + r_1^n$.
The first term $q_* d$ doesn't contribute to the remainder because it's divisible by $d$, so we can forget about it and just divide $r_1^n$ by $d$.